# Not able to get session factory in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

```
        try
        {
            System.out.println("openTxCoreSession() start...");
            TxCoreSessionFactory sessionFactory =
                TxCoreSessionFactory.getInstance("txcore.cfg.xml");
            System.out.println("Session factory created....");

            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            System.out.println("session created");
            return session;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting some sort of exception? If so, what is it?

Comment: TxCoreSessionFactory sessionFactory =
                TxCoreSessionFactory.getInstance("txcore.cfg.xml");
after the above line it is not printing "Session factory created", and does not throw any exception.

Comment: Can you post your "txcore.cfg.xml" file ?

Comment: `TxCoreSessionFactory` is not the hibernate Class. The standard hibernate way to build the SessionFactory is `SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("txcore.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();` Please try it and post the stacktrace as well as `txcore.cfg.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is not easy to start off with, does take a bit of time/effort.

- Found one blog to get started with Hibernate, http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/hibernateintroduction/. But MyEclipse is a priced product. So personally I had to skip it for now.
- I researched more and got Hibernator. Tried Hibernator which is a eclipse plugin to make Hibernate integration super easy (seemed too good to be true), but turned out to be a disaster. Gave it up. Also noticed that the code was as old as 2006, no one working on it now.
- Then moved to Hibernate Tools from JBoss Hibernate Tools – http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/JBossTools-3.1.0.GA worked like a charm.

For people who are confused, MyEclipse or JBoss Hibernate Tools, its no different.

The main reason to use Hibernate on a server platform is to get rid of the complex JDBC hell hole. The only reason you thought you needed a object relational mapping solution was to get some neatness in code and good old re-usability built into the design.

Also the below works for me.

```
           if (sessionFactory == null) {
                try {
                    String jdbcProperty = "jdbc:mysql://"+Globals.DBSERVER+"/MyDB" ;
                    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure() ;                 
                    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                                .buildServiceRegistry());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.fatal("Unable to create SessionFactory for Hibernate");
                    log.fatal(e.getMessage());
                    log.fatal(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Hibernate.properties in the src folder of my eclipse project.

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyDB
hibernate.connection.username=MYROOT
hibernate.connection.password=myPASSWORD
hibernate.connection.pool_size=2
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```

Also ensure that your configuration xml file (txcore.cfg.xml) is in the classpath of your application.

Comment: Yah, but this should throw an error if it does not find txcore.cfg.xml. no?

Comment: Yes, you need to ensure that its in the src of your eclipse project.

Comment: What is the problem, many have commented that you need to define the problem. Please define it. Not possible to pin point help unless you specify.

Comment: Paste contents of your properties file here.